# Cypher/Neo4J: How to find interconnected neighbors_of_neighbors

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am playing around with Neo4J, and I have nodes of persons and cities visited. Lets say that I have visited London, and I want to see  I want to create a query returning all cities that has been visited by more than one of the persons that have visited a city you have visited. However, it must not be a city that you have visited. Whoa, that was a mouthful.

I've created an example case. In this example, the query in question would return the city of Paris.

Paste it in http://console.neo4j.org/ to play with it.

create (Chris:person {name:'Chris'}),(Jeff:person {name:'Jeff'}),(Pete:person {name:'Pete'}),(Alex:person{name:'Alex'}),(John:person {name:'John'}),(London:city {name:'London'}),(Paris:city {name:'Paris'}),(Mumbay:city {name:'Mumbay'}),(Moskva:city {name:'Moskva'}),(Seattle:city {name:'Seattle'}),(Chris)-[:VISITED]->(London),(Jeff)-[:VISITED]->(London),(John)-[:VISITED]->(London),(Jeff)-[:VISITED]->(Paris),(John)-[:VISITED]->(Paris),(Jeff)-[:VISITED]->(Seattle),(London)-[:VISITED_BY]->(Chris),(London)-[:VISITED_BY]->(Jeff),(London)-[:VISITED_BY]->(John),(Paris)-[:VISITED_BY]->(Jeff),(Paris)-[:VISITED_BY]->(John),(Seattle)-[:VISITED_BY]->(Jeff),(Pete)-[:VISITED]->(Seattle),(Seattle)-[:VISITED_BY]->(Pete),(Chris)-[:VISITED]->(Mumbay),(Mumbay)-[:VISITED_BY]->(Chris),(Alex)-[:VISITED]->(Mumbay),(Mumbay)-[:VISITED_BY]->(Alex),(Alex)-[:VISITED]->(Moskva),(Moskva)-[:VISITED_BY]->(Alex),(Pete)-[:VISITED]->(Moskva),(Moskva)-[:VISITED_BY]->(Pete)

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used your data to create a GraphGist: http://www.neo4j.org/graphgist?66acb4a7e53be6181449

Assuming the person to base queries on is Chris:

```
MATCH (chris:person { name:'Chris' })-[:VISITED]->(city)<-[:VISITED]-(otherPerson)
MATCH (otherPerson)-[:VISITED]->(otherCity)
WHERE otherCity<>city
WITH otherCity.name AS cityName, collect(otherPerson.name) AS persons
WHERE length(persons)> 1
RETURN cityName
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I'd also like to make a query showing the paths to Paris (e.g. Myself->London->[John,Jeff]->Paris) and only this. Any idea how that could be done?

Comment: Never mind,looks like i did it:

MATCH (chris:person { name:'Chris' })-[:VISITED]->(city)<-[:VISITED]-(otherPerson)
MATCH (otherPerson)-[:VISITED]->(otherCity)
WITH user, otherCity, collect(otherPerson) AS persons
WHERE length(persons)> 1
RETURN chris, persons, otherCity, length(persons)

Comment: Great- add the otherCity<>city to eliminate London though